# Getting all attributes from an <a> HTML tag with regex

Tags: php, html, regex, pcre

I already have a function that retrieves the `href` attribute from all of the `a` tags on a given page of markup. However, I would also like to retrieve other attributes, namely the `title` attribute.

I have a feeling it's a simple modification of the regular expression that I'm already using, but my only concern is the order of appearance in the markup. If I have a link with this code:

```
<a href="somepage.html" title="My Page">link text</a>
```

I want it to be parsed the same and not cause any errors even if it appears like this:

```
<a title="My Page" href="somepage.html">link text</a>
```

Here is my processing function:

```
function getLinks($src) {
    if(preg_match_all('/<a\s+href=["\']([^"\']+)["\']/i', $src, $links, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER))
        return array_unique($links[1]);
    return false;
}
```

Would I have to use another regex all together, or would it be possible to modify this one so that the `title` attribute is stored in the same array of returned data as the `href` attribute?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Just as a tip, you should probably be using a proper HTML parser instead of regular expressions.

Comment: Any suggestions on HTML parsers? I tend to the do things the hard way (unknowingly) so I'm not familiar with any.

Comment: @danl Take a look at the suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build on that regex.  Have a look:

```
'/<a(?:\s+(?:href=["\'](?P<href>[^"\'<>]+)["\']|title=["\'](?P<title>[^"\'<>]+)["\']|\w+=["\'][^"\'<>]+["\']))+/i'
```

...or in human-readable form:

```
preg_match_all(
    '/<a
    (?:\s+
      (?:
         href=["\'](?P<href>[^"\'<>]+)["\']
        |
         title=["\'](?P<title>[^"\'<>]+)["\']
        |
         \w+=["\'][^"\'<>]+["\']
      )
    )+/ix', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Pretty self explanatory, I think.  Note that your original regex has the same problem vis-à-vis order of appearance.  For example, it would fail to match this tag:

```
<a class="someclass" href="somepage.html">link text</a>
```

Unless you're absolutely sure there will be no other attributes, you can't reasonably expect `href` to be listed first.  You can use the same gimmick as above, where the second branch silently consumes and discards the attributes that don't interest you:

```
    '/<a
    (?:\s+
      (?:
         href=["\'](?P<href>[^"\'<>]+)["\']
        |
         \w+=["\'][^"\'<>]+["\']
      )
    )+/ix',
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [regextrainer](http://regextrainer.bitsequence.net) I made a while back.

The sample contains a pattern like this: `<([^ ]+) ?([^>]*)>([^<]*)< ?/ ?\1>` which will capture attributes in html.

I see now that it doesn't extract the attribute name and value, just the whole attribute text itself. Use this to extract the attribute details: `((([^=]+)=((?:"|'))([^"']+)\4) ?)+`

Comment: the trainer is offline now